# Organizing Ember.js models inside sub-folders?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have multiple models representing user data (profile, settings etc).
These at the moment are stored in the models folder like so;

```
models
  -> user.js
  -> profile.js
  -> settings.js
```

What I would like to so is have a folder structure like so;

```
models
  -> user.js
  -> user (folder)
    -> profile.js
    -> settings.js
```

The user model (user.js) references the profile model (profile.js) like so;

```
import DS from "ember-data"; 
export default DS.Model.extend({
   NSP: DS.attr('string'),
   Status: DS.attr('string'),
   Profile: DS.belongsTo('profile', {embedded: 'always'})
});
```

I have tried to replace the `DS.belongsTo('profile', {embedded: 'always'})` with the following:

- `DS.belongsTo('user.profile', {embedded: 'always'})`
- `DS.belongsTo('user/profile', {embedded: 'always'})`
- `DS.belongsTo('user-profile', {embedded: 'always'})`

but this does not work.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure using "user/profile" doesn't work? 
I replicated your structure on my system and am getting "user" and "user/profile" models.

Do you have Ember Inspector installed on Firefox or Chrome? You can see the available models easily by going to the "Data" pane:[image]

Comment: So when `profile` model is under `user` folder i.e `user/profile`,  
How do you run createRecord or peekAll ? 
By this way ~> 
`this.store.createRecord('user/profile');`
`this.store.peekAll('user/profile');`
or any other work around ?

Comment: @rinold you'd be best asking that as a new question. I've not used Ember in years so can't give you an answer off the top of my head.